# How to reduce the temp object when using push_back and getline?

Tags: c++, list, constructor, getline, push-back

I found [an example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) about how to use `std::getline()`, and this is the code snippet:

```
std::istringstream input("abc|def|gh");
std::vector<std::array<char, 4>> v;

for (std::array<char, 4> a; input.getline(&a[0], 4, '|'); )
    v.push_back(a);
```

We can find that `a` is constructed at the for-loop, and it is passed into `push_back` as an argument. Is there a better way to make sure there is no temporary object like `a` to avoid overhead?

I have found a member function called `emplace_back()` to reduce the use of temporary object, but I am not sure how can I use it in this case, or I should just leave it for compiler optimizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getline` needs to have a location to get the line in to, but you can make that location be the new element in the `v` vector, thus avoiding the use of an extra variable.  Replace the `for` loop with a `do/while` loop:

```
do {
    v.emplace_back();
} while (input.getline(&v.back()[0], 4, '|'));
v.pop_back();
```

The `emplace_back` takes the place of `a` in your original code.

Comment: I think there should have a `v.pop_back()` at the end. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to make sure there is no temporary object like `a` to avoid overhead?

If you know the size of the `vector` ahead of time, you create one with the known size and use the preallocated members of the vector in the call to `getline`.

```
size_t size = 10;
std::istringstream input("abc|def|gh");
std::vector<std::array<char, 4>> v(size); // Assuming size of the vector.

for ( size_t i = 0; i < size && input.getline(&v[i], 4, '|'); ++i ) {}
```